# What are all these folders on the left?

Tags: nautilus, directory, filemanager, shared-folders

I booted up Ubuntu today, and I noticed these folders in my file manager. Whenever I open the file manager now it freezes for like 2 minutes before I can do anything. And if I click on any them I get an error message that pops up. The picture if of the error, but you should be able to see the folders I'm talking about. There's like 100+ of these folders.

[image: Error Message In question]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like an Xorg log. Have you changed anything regarding the X server?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything really. I've installed a few things. But I haven't messed around too much for fear of wrecking everything.

Answer (score 0):

These are network drives, judging from their icon. The file manager seems to have a problem with their names probably because of the square brackets. Do you have any software running that might connect to a large numer of network shares or exports? Scanning for them, perchance?
Would be easier to guess at what's going on if you'd enlarge the left column so that the names are fully visible.

Comment: Here is a few pictures that have the sidebar extended. As far as I know I don't have any software that would do that. 

https://imgur.com/a/R5uhtdF
https://imgur.com/a/uYEx5VG

Comment: OK, this is officially weird. I have no idea what happens there. It looks like your file manager interprets things as network drives that aren't, like local directory listings and kernel's names.

Comment: Any idea if it would be safe to remove them? Or if there's a way to batch remove them since there's a ton of them.